# Find if column has identity from other database on same server in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, identity

I am having problem to find Identity applied on table with specific columnName or not from different database on same server(using Information_schema):

Following line of query use to find if identity applied on column or not from same database:

```
if exists( Select OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id('TableName'), 'TableHasIdentity')) --This give result from same database
begin
    print 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ARCHIVE_Database.dbo.TableName ON'
    print 'insert into ARCHIVE_Database.dbo.TableName(ID,Name) values 1,''Ankush'' '
    print 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ARCHIVE_Database.dbo.TableName OFF'
end
else
    print 'insert into ARCHIVE_Database.dbo.TableName(ID,Name) values 1,''Ankush'' '
```

Can we replace `Select   OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id('TableName'), 'TableHasIdentity'))` line to find identity applied on table or not from database `ARCHIVE_Database`

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you mean finding out whether an identity column exists in a table in another database that the one you are currently in:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
from ARCHIVE_Database.sys.tables t
INNER JOIN ARCHIVE_Database.sys.columns c
    ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.object_id = OBJECT_ID('ARCHIVE_Database.dbo.TableName') AND is_identity = 1)
BEGIN
   ...
END
```